# Could you trace how this Haskell foldl lambda function is working?

Tags: debugging, haskell, trace, fold

```
myReverse :: [a] -> [a]
myReverse = foldl (\a x -> x:a) []

foldl is (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
```

The lambda function is obviously in the brackets. Where does `foldl` get its initial value from?  And what is `[b]` in this case?

Answer (score 2):

We can step through the evaluation of, say, `myReverse [1,2,3]`. We need the definition of `foldl`

```
foldl f z []     = z
foldl f z (x:xs) = foldl f (f z x) xs
```

So we have

```
myReverse [1,2,3,4]
-- definition of myReverse
= foldl (\a x -> x:a) [] [1,2,3]
-- definition of foldl (x:xs case)
= foldl (\a x -> x:a) ((\a x -> x:a) [] 1) [2,3]
-- beta reduction [1]
= foldl (\a x -> x:a) [1] [2,3]
-- definition of foldl
= foldl (\a x -> x:a) ((\a x -> x:a) [1] 2) [3]
-- beta reduction
= foldl (\a x -> x:a) [2,1] [3]
-- definition of foldl
= foldl (\a x -> x:a) ((\a x -> x:a) [2,1] 3) []
-- beta reduction
= foldl (\a x -> x:a) [3,2,1] []
-- definition of foldl ([] case)
= [3,2,1]
```

with the important caveat at [1] and for each beta reduction step that this beta reduction actually only happens when something scrutinizes the result. As `foldl` is progressing, the repeated applications of `f` build up as thunks, so what we really get (if `f = \a x -> x:a`) is:

```
foldl f [] [1,2,3]
foldl f (f [] 1) [2,3]
foldl f ((f 2 (f [] 1))) [3]
foldl f (((f 3 ((f 2 (f [] 1)))))) []
(((f 3 ((f 2 (f [] 1))))))
```

This is why we have `foldl'`, which is strict in its accumulator and prevents this thunk build-up.

The initial value is `[]`. The `[b]` in this case is the same as the `a` in `foldl`, which is the `[a]` in `myReverse`.

Answer (score 0):

```
myReverse :: [a] -> [a]
myReverse = foldl (\a x -> x:a) []
```

can be equivalently rewritten as

```
myReverse :: [a] -> [a]
myReverse xs = foldl (\a x -> x:a) [] xs
```

Hence, the folding function is the lambda `\a x -> x:a`, the starting value is `[]`, and the list to fold over is `xs`.